# In swagger-api code i am getting paths{},description{} and response{} etc as empty

Tags: node.js, express, swagger

I am using Express and Node. I am following the below link to get my swagger documentation for the APIs: http://mherman.org/blog/2016/05/26/swagger-and-nodejs/#.We8gq2iCzDc. I have the same project structure. I am sure there is something missing yet I am unable to find the mistake. Any help is appreciated.

This is my app.js:

```
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';

var routes = require('./routes/routes');

var swaggerJSDoc = require('swagger-jsdoc');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var swaggerDefinition = {
info: {
    title: 'Node Swagger API',
    version: '1.0.0',
    description: 'Demonstrating how to describe a RESTful API with Swagger',
},
host: 'localhost:3000',
basePath: '/',
};
var options = {
swaggerDefinition: swaggerDefinition,
apis: ['./routes/routes.js']
};

var swaggerSpec = swaggerJSDoc(options);

class Server {
constructor() {
    this.app = express();
}

configureApp() {
    this.app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 3000));
    this.app.use(bodyParser.json());
    this.app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    this.app.use(bodyParser());
    this.app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
    this.app.use('/', routes);
}

configureCORS() {

    this.app.use((req, res, next) => {

        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, PUT, DELETE, GET');
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With');

        res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
        next();
    });
}

configureRoutes() {
    this.app.post('/api/doctorPost', doctor.post);
    this.app.put('/api/doctorEdit/:id', doctor.put);
    this.app.delete('/api/doctorDelete/:id', doctor.delete);*/
    this.app.get('/swagger.json', function(req, res) {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.send(swaggerSpec);
    });
}

listen(port) {
    this.app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`Server started: http://localhost:${port}/`);
    });
}

run() {
    this.configureApp();
    this.configureCORS()
    this.configureRoutes();
    this.listen(this.app.get('port'));
}
}

export default Server;
```

This is my routes.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var api = require('../doctor.api');

/**
* @swagger
* definition:
*   doctor:
*   type: object
*   properties:
*     id:
*      type: integer
*    name:
*       type: string
*    picUrl:
*       type: string
*    briefDescription:
*       type: string
*     speciality:
*      type: string
*    exprience:
*     type: string
*   description:
*      type: string
*    contact:
*      type: string
*    email:
*      type: string
*    phoneno:
*      type: integer
*    status:
*      type: string
*      description: doctor Status
*     enum:
*         - available
*         - pending
*         - not exists
*    waitingTime:
*      type: integer
*      format: int64
*     rating:
*       type: integer
*      format: int64
*     videoUrl:
*       type: string
*     appearUrl:
*       type: string
*    collapseId:
*      type: string
*    thumbnailUrl:
*      type: string
*    lastUpdateTime:
*      type: integer
*      format: int64
*/

/**
* @swagger
* /api/doctorGet:
*   get:
*     tags:
*       - doctor
*     description: Returns all doctor
*     produces:
*       - application/json
*     responses:
*       200:
*         description: An array of doctor
*         schema:
*           $ref: '#/definitions/doctor'
*/
router.get('/api/doctorGet', api.getDoctors);

/** 
* @swagger
* /api/doctorPost:
*  post:
*    tags:
*       - doctor
*     summary: Add a new doctor to the list
*     description: New doctor added
*     operationId: addDoctor
*    consumes:
*      - application/json
*      - application/xml
*     produces:
*       - application/xml
*       - application/json
*     parameters:
*       - in: body
*         name: body
*        description: Doctor object that needs to be added to the list
*        required: true
*        schema:
*           $ref: '#/definitions/doctor'
*    responses:
*       '405':
*         description: Invalid input
*     security:
*       - doctor_auth:
*           - 'write:doctor'
*          - 'read:doctor'
*/
 router.post('/api/doctorPost', api.createDoctor);

/**
* @swagger
* /api/doctorEdit/{id}:
*   put:
*     tags:
*       - doctor
*     description: Updates a single doctor
*     produces:
*       - application/json
*     parameters:
*       - name: id
*         description: doctor's id
*         in: path
*         required: true
*         type: integer
*       - name: puppy
*         description: doctor object
*         in: body
*         required: true
*         schema:
*           $ref: '#/definitions/doctor'
*     responses:
*       200:
*         description: Successfully updated      
*/
router.put('/api/doctorEdit/:id', api.updateDoctor);

 /**
 * @swagger
 * /api/doctorDelete/{id}:
 *   delete:
 *     tags:
 *       - doctor
 *     description: Deletes a single doctor
 *     produces:
 *       - application/json
 *     parameters:
 *       - name: id
 *         description: doctor's id
 *         in: path
 *         required: true
 *         type: integer
 *     responses:
 *       200:
 *         description: Successfully deleted
 */
 router.delete('/api/doctorDelete/:id', api.deleteDoctor);


 module.exports = router;
```

My output is:

> {"info":{"title":"Node Swagger 
>   API","version":"1.0.0","description":"Demonstrating how to describe a 
>   RESTful API with  Swagger"},"host":"localhost:3000","basePath":"/","swagger":"2.0","paths":
>   {},"definitions":{},"responses":{},"parameters":{},"securityDefinitions":{}}

Expected output would be something like this:

> {"info":{"title":"Node Swagger 
>   API","version":"1.0.0","description":"Demonstrating how to desribe a RESTful API with Swagger"},"host":"localhost:3000","basePath":"/","swagger":"2.0","paths":{"/api/puppies":{"get":{"tags":["Puppies"],"description":"Returns all puppies","produces":["application/json"],"responses":{"200":{"description":"An array of puppies","schema":{"$ref":"#/definitions/Puppy"}}}},"post":{"tags":["Puppies"],"description":"Creates a new puppy","produces":["application/json"],"parameters":[{"name":"puppy","description":"Puppy object","in":"body","required":true,"schema":{"$ref":"#/definitions/Puppy"}}],"responses":{"200":{"description":"Successfully created"}}}},"/api/puppies/{id}":{"get":{"tags":["Puppies"],"description":"Returns a single puppy","produces":["application/json"],"parameters":[{"name":"id","description":"Puppy's id","in":"path","required":true,"type":"integer"}],"responses":{"200":{"description":"A single puppy","schema":{"$ref":"#/definitions/Puppy"}}}},"put":{"tags":["Puppies"],"description":"Updates a single puppy","produces":["application/json"],"parameters":[{"name":"id","description":"Puppy's id","in":"path","required":true,"type":"integer"},{"name":"puppy","description":"Puppy object","in":"body","required":true,"schema":{"$ref":"#/definitions/Puppy"}}],"responses":{"200":{"description":"Successfully updated"}}},"delete":{"tags":["Puppies"],"description":"Deletes a single puppy","produces":["application/json"],"parameters":[{"name":"id","description":"Puppy's id","in":"path","required":true,"type":"integer"}],"responses":{"200":{"description":"Successfully deleted"}}}}},"definitions":{"Puppy":{"properties":{"name":{"type":"string"},"breed":{"type":"string"},"age":{"type":"integer"},"sex":{"type":"string"}}}},"responses":{},"parameters":{},"securityDefinitions":{},"tags":[]}

Comment: I think you forgot to call the `run` function. You declared it but I do not see any function call to it. Please add it and try again.

Comment: Maybe add it to the `constructor` after creating the express app.

Comment: I have called run function in index.js file from where my application is starting.

Comment: my index.js code is                                                                                 import Server from './server';
var server = new Server();
server.run();